# Subversion choosing it's own revisions to merge from and to?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-and-merging

So today I got stumped, merging revisions of trunk into a branch working copy.

```
svn merge -r 7587:7735 http://OurProject/trunk
 --- Merging r7649 through r7735 into '.':
```

It looks like the merge info is broken since it lists the merges from trunk as

/trunk:7446-7648

but we only merged up to 7587 from 7446.

So why is the mergeinfo wrong, how does this happen?

Thanks

Piers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ending up answering this one myself.

The merge info was correct, we f**ked up and merged all those revisions (7587-7648) but then reverted all the actual changes from them before comitting, thus making it look like SVN had got its knickers in a twist when in fact it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out what is going on from the description. However, Subversion does do a very good job at tracking changes, so it is probably doing the right thing.

The revisions listed as a result of the `svn merge` might not necessarily agree with the range you gave it because those revisions might not be on trunk. That's why it's showing you revision 7649 instead of revision 7587 as the first revision of the merge.

I don't know whether the `svn:mergeinfo`, you're looking at is pre or post merge. However, as long as the branches involved in the merge have a ***direct*** common ancestor, and you didn't do something silly like deleting all files on a branch and re-adding them back in, everything should be fine with the merge.

Comment: Thanks for the info David W, your comment confirms my answer.